# Can Sitecore content hub DAM support .exe asset type?

Tags: content-hub

There is a requirement in my project to upload `.exe` files in Sitecore DAM. Can Sitecore Content Hub DAM support `.exe` asset type?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload `.exe` files in Sitecore Content Hub DAM however by default `.exe` (among others) will be in a list of extensions not allowed.

To change this, go into your `Creation component` (Manage -> Pages -> Create and select 'Creation' on the top right, in the `HEADER ZONE (RIGHT)` area). Select the 'Upload files' option, and remove `.exe` from the `Allowed extensions` field:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No.Sitecore content hub won't support .exe file type.

The supported asset media types in Sitecore DAM - https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.2.x/content/user-documentation/manage-digital-assets/asset-types/asset-types.html

Comment: Any workaround to support the .exe file?

Comment: You can zip the .exe asset file and upload in SCH.